# Get Button click position on indexOf array from a component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Thank you in advance,
I'm trying get the position of a button on the array after the button was click. The button is part of a group component.

the component is this:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="eventoConcluido", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function endEventBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var eventTerminado:Event = new Event("eventoConcluido");
            dispatchEvent(eventTerminado);

            //this.removeAllElements();
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button id="endEvent" label="Test" color="black" width="100" click="endEventBtn(event);" />
```

And in application try to get this:

```
private var myArray:Array = [];
private var myButton:Button;
protected var comp1:test;

public function addButton():void {  

    comp1= new test();
    myGroup.addElement(comp1);
    myArray.push(myGroup.addElement(comp1));
    comp1.endEvent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getButton);
}

public function getButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var ij:int= myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
    trace(ij)// always get -1;
}



<s:Button label="Add Button" click="addButton();" />
```

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` references the Button being clicked on, but you didn't push that Button into the Array. You pushed `comp1` into the Array, which is actually that Button's parent.

Option 1 - Push the Button into the array instead of the parent:

```
public function addButton():void {
    comp1 = new test();
    myGroup.addElement(comp1);
    myArray.push(comp1.endEvent);
    comp1.endEvent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getButton);
}

public function getButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var ij:int= myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
}
```

Option 2 - Do the index check on the parent instead of the child:

```
public function addButton():void {
    comp1 = new test();
    myGroup.addElement(comp1);
    myArray.push(comp1);
    comp1.endEvent.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getButton);
}

public function getButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var ij:int= myArray.indexOf(event.currentTarget.owner);
}
```

Comment: thank you Karma, work perfect the Option2. I´m very grateful for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered if you are satisfied.